# filled array is empty outside function

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, each

I try to push in my array looped data from ajax json but the data variable outside `$.getJSON("/admin/reports/stats/1", function(datas) {});` is empty

```
var data = [];
$.getJSON("/admin/reports/stats/1", function(datas) {
    $(datas).each(function(index, value){
        obj={};
        obj['label']= value.publisher_name;
        obj['data']=  value.sale;
        data.push(obj);
    });
    console.log(data); //here I see the content of array    
});

console.log(data); //here is empty
```

Comment: You'll find an answer AND an explanation [here](http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript).

Comment: use .done() and perform you operation there on your datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getJSON is asynchronous, so this:

```
console.log(data); //here is empty
```

is actually executed before JSON could be downloaded.